# This code work for only 4 or 5 iteration, how is this possible?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, genetic

my code is genetic algorithm and its only works for 4-5 times and after 4-5. work, suddenly stops and gives error "IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22" ,I paid attention to making "-1" to avoid index error, but the code still insists on stopping. It's genetic algorithm code, and its solving traveling salesman problem, its gives error when crossOver time.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""
import numpy as np
import copy
coord=[]
coord = np.array([[11, 47, 62],       
       [31, 37, 69],
       [32, 38, 46],
       [33, 46, 10],
       [34, 61, 33],
       [35, 62, 63],
       [36, 63, 69],
       [37, 32, 22],
       [38, 45, 35],
       [39, 59, 15],
       [40, 5, 6],
       [41, 10, 17],
       [42, 21, 10],
       [43, 5, 64],
       [44, 30, 15],
       [45, 39, 10],
       [46, 32, 39],
       [47, 25, 32],
       [48, 25, 55],
       [49, 48, 28],
       [50, 56, 37],
       [61, 40, 50]],dtype=np.int)
city=len(coord)
best_solution=[]
best_fitness=100000000
pop_size=1000  
CR=0.5 # %YÜZDE 90 OLASILIKLA CAPRAZLANIYOR.
# MR=0.5
MR=5

MaxIter=5000



# distance = np.zeros((coord.shape[0], coord.shape[0]))
distance = np.zeros([city,city])

for i in range(city):
    for j in range(city):
        distance[i][j] = np.sqrt((coord[i][1] - coord[j][1]) ** 2 + (coord[i][2] - coord[j][2]) ** 2)

population=np.zeros([pop_size,city],dtype=np.int)     
for i in range(pop_size):
    population[i][:]=np.random.permutation(city)

fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])   


for i in range(pop_size):
    fitness[0][i]=0
    for j in range(city-1):
        # fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
        fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]
    fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]]
    if best_fitness > fitness[0][i]: 
        best_solution=population[i][:]
        best_fitness=fitness[0][i]   
        denemeFit= best_fitness                   

b=np.min(fitness) # there is no lower than this value but it gives 13 or 20.

   # while dongusu gelecek*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
iteration=0;
fitness=1000./fitness
while iteration<MaxIter:
    total=np.sum(fitness)
    n_fitness=fitness/total
    c_fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])  
    c_fitness[0][0]=n_fitness[0][0]        
    for i in range(1,pop_size):
          c_fitness[0][i]=n_fitness[0][0]+c_fitness[0][i-1]     
    c_count=-1
    c_pop=np.zeros([pop_size,city],dtype=np.int) 

    while c_count < pop_size-1: # while dongusu gelecek*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
                 r=np.random.rand()
                 for i in range(pop_size-1):
                    if c_fitness[0][i] >= r:
                        p1=i
                        break

                 p2=p1
                 while p2==p1:
                    r=np.random.rand()
                    for i in range(pop_size-1):
                        if c_fitness[0][i] >= r:
                            p2=i
                            break

                 r1=np.random.rand()        
                 if r1 < CR:
                    parent1=population[p1][:]
                    parent2=population[p2][:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    point1=np.random.randint(city-1)
                    point2=point1
                    while abs(point1-point2)<4:
                        point2=np.random.randint(city-1)
                    if point2<point1:
                                deepo=point2
                                point2=point1
                                point1=deepo    

                    child1=copy.copy(parent1)
                    child2=copy.copy(parent2)       

                    # copy_list = org_list[:] 

                    counter=point1
                    for i in range(city-1):    
                        for j in range(point1+1,point2):
                            if parent2[i]==parent1[j]:
                                counter=counter+1
                                child1[counter]=parent2[i]
                    counter=point1            
                    for i in range(city-1):    
                        for j in range(point1+1,point2):
                            if parent1[i]==parent2[j]:
                                counter=counter+1
                                child2[counter]=parent1[i]   

                    c_count=c_count+2
                    c_pop[c_count-1][:]=child1   
                    c_pop[c_count][:]=child2    


    c_fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])                   
    for i in range(pop_size):
        c_fitness[0][i]=0
        for j in range(city-1):
            # fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
            c_fitness[0][i]=c_fitness[0][i]+ distance[c_pop[i][j]][c_pop[i][j+1]]
        c_fitness[0][i]=c_fitness[0][i]+ distance[c_pop[i][city-1]][c_pop[i][1]]
        if best_fitness > c_fitness[0][i]: 
            best_solution=c_pop[i][:]
            best_fitness=c_fitness[0][i]                 


    m_pop=copy.copy(c_pop)
    for i in range(pop_size):
        r2=np.random.rand()
        if r2 <= MR:
            city1=np.random.randint(city-1)
            city2=city1
            while city2==city1:
                city2=np.random.randint(city-1)

            deepo=m_pop[i][city1]
            m_pop[i][city1]=m_pop[i][city2]
            m_pop[i][city2]=deepo

    m_fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])        
    for i in range(pop_size):
        m_fitness[0][i]=0
        for j in range(city-1):
            # fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
            m_fitness[0][i]=m_fitness[0][i]+ distance[m_pop[i][j]][m_pop[i][j+1]]
        m_fitness[0][i]=m_fitness[0][i]+ distance[m_pop[i][city-1]][m_pop[i][1]]
        if best_fitness > m_fitness[0][i]: 
            best_solution=m_pop[i][:]
            best_fitness=m_fitness[0][i]     

    population=copy.copy(m_pop)
    fitness=copy.copy(m_fitness)
    population[1][:]=best_solution
    fitness[0][1]=best_fitness
    iteration=iteration+1
    print(iteration) 
    print(best_fitness)
    # print(best_solution)
```

it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\\Google Drive\python\untitled0.py", line 135, in <module>
    child2[counter]=parent1[i]

IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22
```

Comment: yes, there is. I can see them in varable explorer.  If it were, it would not even work 1 time. you can see parent1 or child2 with "print (child2)" .

Comment: My apology, I didn't know that your code is **THAT** long. I'm not sure it's a good ideal to post such a long piece of code here and expect people to debug it for you.

Comment: ı think its a basic index problem that ı dont know. thats why i posted code.

Comment: When indexng 2d arrays, you should use `coord[j,1]` not `coord[j][1]`.  In particular when doing `population[i][:]`, the `[:]` does nothing.  You need to read more about numpy arrays, and not just assume they are nested lists.  This may not be causing your problem, but it indicates that you have written this code without much basic numpy reading.

Comment: i understood you but, there is no problem with creating childs and parents. childs and parents created true. also, coord[3,2] and coord[3][2] returns same value?

Comment: its `counter` that's causing the problem as it becomes `> 21`. I cant see how it is related to the iteration count though but yes always crashes on the same iteration everytime. Good luck

Comment: `child2[counter]=parent1[i]` error means that either `counter` or `i` is 22, while the first dimension of `child2` or `parent1` is 22.  You are indexing.  Looks like `coord` is (22,3), so arrays derived from that might have the same shape.  With expressions like `counter=counter+1` it is hard to prevent `counter` from getting too large.  `for i in range(22)` is more secure.  Any ways, your handling of these indices is convoluted and hard to debug!.

Comment: point1 and point 2 cannot bigger than 21, but counter= counter+1 because of that, i made that, point1 and 2 derived from permutation(20), its still returns same error.  counter cannot bigger than point2, i really dont understand.

Comment: if its wrong, how codes runs for  4 or 5 times?

Answer (score 2):

OK found the problem. In the following loops `counter` can indeed end up `>21`

```
counter=point1
for i in range(city-1):    
    for j in range(point1+1,point2):
        if parent2[i]==parent1[j]:
            counter=counter+1
            child1[counter]=parent2[i]

counter=point1            
for i in range(city-1):    
    for j in range(point1+1,point2):
        if parent1[i]==parent2[j]:
            counter=counter+1
            child2[counter]=parent1[i]
```

Consider the case when for every iteration of `j` that `if parent2[i]==parent1[j]:` is `True` then `counter` is incremented by `j` times multiplied by `city-1` times which can easily by above `21` as `city-1 = 21`

To remedy it you need to reset `counter` for each iteration of the `i` loop,

```
for i in range(city-1):
    counter=point1    
    for j in range(point1+1,point2):
        if parent2[i]==parent1[j]:
            counter=counter+1
            child1[counter]=parent2[i]

for i in range(city-1): 
    counter=point1   
    for j in range(point1+1,point2):
        if parent1[i]==parent2[j]:
            counter=counter+1
            child2[counter]=parent1[i]
```

Comment: it doesnt returns error but, it works wrong. each child must be different, this causes same  genes in chromosome. child1 is a route that going one city to another.

Comment: I cant comment on the rest of the logic of your problem but that's why you were getting an out of range error... you're welcome.

Comment: thanks for your attention.